# Override required property on apex:inputField so that page can refresh?

Tags: visualforce-component, custom-controller, fieldsets, required-field

I'm using fieldSets on a visualforce component and form. There is a formula `{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}` for the `required` property. Main question, does this have to be modified with JavaScript?

The users click a `Edit` button to open the InputFields `Apex:repeat` component. I want the user to be able to close the edit version if the user decides to go to a different part of the form. However, right now, the browser is reading the required field before it is getting to the controller it seems like. I have also attempted to add a conditional on the required field, but this also does not seem to work.

### VF Component

```
<apex:component controller="HB_BS_UserAboutCard" allowDML="true">

<apex:form id="theForm">
        
            <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand" action="{!displayEditComponent}" value="Edit COMPONENT" rendered="{!!isEdit}" />

            <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand" action="{!save}" value="Save" rendered="{!isEdit}" rerender="theForm" status="pageSavingStatus"/>
            
            <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand"  action="{!refreshPage}" rendered="{!isEdit}"  value="Cancel"  status="pageSavingStatus"/>  
            
            
            <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="f" rendered="{!!isEdit}">
                <div class="slds-form-element">
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-53">{!f.label}</label>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
                        <apex:outputField 
                            styleClass="slds-input" 
                            value="{!userAbout[f.fieldPath]}"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </apex:repeat>
            <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="f" rendered="{!isEdit}" id="inputFields">
                <div class="slds-form-element">
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-53">{!f.label}</label>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
                        <apex:inputField 
                            styleClass="slds-input" 
                            value="{!userAbout[f.fieldPath]}"  
                            required = "{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </apex:repeat>
            <apex:actionStatus id="pageSavingStatus">
                <apex:facet name="start">
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                        <img src="/img/loading32.gif" width="25" height="25" />
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Saving..."/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>            
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionStatus>
    </apex:form>
```

#### Controller

```
public with sharing class HB_BS_UserAboutCard {
    public HB_BS_UserAboutCard() {
        this.isEdit = false; 
        
        this.userAbout = getUserAboutCard();
    }
    // public Boolean isActive{get;set;}

    public User userAbout {get;set;} 
    public Boolean isEdit {get;set;}
    public Boolean isError{get;set;}
    
    
    public  User  getUserAboutCard(){
        String query = 'SELECT ';
        String userId = UserInfo.getUserId();  
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getFields()){
            query += f.getFieldPath() + ', '; 
        }
        query += 'Id FROM User WHERE Id =: userId LIMIT 1'; 
        
        return Database.query(query);  
    }
    // User Fields 
    public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields(){
        return SObjectType.User.FieldSets.HB_BS_UserAboutCard.getFields();
        // return     Schema.SObjectType.Account.fieldSets.getMap().get(fieldNames).getFields();

    }

    public void displayEditComponent(){
        this.isEdit = true; 
   }

   public void hideEditComponent(){
        
        this.isEdit = false; 
   }

   public Pagereference refreshPage(){
       this.userAbout = getUserAboutCard();
       this.isEdit = false;
        
       PageReference secondPage = Page.HB_BS_POC;
       secondPage.setRedirect(true);
       return null; 
   }

   public void save(){
       
       try {
           this.isEdit = false;     
           update userAbout;
           PageReference secondPage = Page.HB_BS_POC;
           secondPage.setRedirect(true);
           ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Successfully Updated'));
         
       } catch (DmlException ex) {
        // ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'My Error Message');
 

       }

     
       
   }

    
   
}
```

Comment: where is `fields` defined in the controller?

Comment: fields is not in the controller. It's from scheme.fieldMember class. getRequired.

Comment: @cropredy added the way the fieldset is being grabbed.

Comment: the normal way to bypass required fields is to use an action where `immediate="true"`

Comment: I'll give that a shot.